# Command-+ style zooming in iOS Safari

Tags: ios, safari, zoom

I'd like to be able to zoom in on a web page in iOS Safari the way you can in the Mac OS version using Command-+. Note that this is different than pinch/spread zooming in iOS. If I spread my fingers to zoom a page, everything is magnified but the browser window just gets wider so you can no longer see the whole thing, making side to side panning necessary. On a well-designed web page, if I use Command-+ to zoom in, everything gets larger but the margins don't change. The text gets bigger and re-flows so that it still fits in the same margins. Is there a way to do that in Safari on iOS?

Comment: Either pinching to zoom on your trackpad, double tapping with two fingers on your trackpad, or double tapping with on finger on your magic mouse will do this.

Comment: I'm asking about doing this on an iOS device, not on a Mac. On a Mac, Command-+ does what I want. Pinch zooming on iOS does not do the same thing, as I explained in my original post.

Comment: Ohh sorry I read it wrong, I was thinking you wanted it to happen on your mac as it does in iOS. Unfortunately the only way to really do this is by going into settings>display & brightness>text size and changing it. It's not very elegant and will not work on all sites. I may have a javascript work around though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with native iOS controls. A work around is a Javascript bookmarklet. First, bookmark any page and then bookmark another page. Then, choose bookmarks and edit them. For the first one, rename it the minus (-) symbol and change the URL to:

`javascript:var p=document.getElementsByTagName('*');for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){if(p[i].style.fontSize){var s=parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));}else{var s=12;}s-=2;p[i].style.fontSize=s+"px"}`

Do the same for the other bookmark, but rename it the plus symbol (+) and change the URL to:

`javascript:var p=document.getElementsByTagName('*');for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){if(p[i].style.fontSize){var s=parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));}else{var s=12;}s+=2;p[i].style.fontSize=s+"px"}`

Now to increase or decrease the size of text, simply tap the bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it but it doesn't seem to reliably increase/decrease the font size.